# GraphicsMagick how do you use it to get the image in to the desktop as wall paper?

Tags: wallpaper, graphicsmagick, desktop-wallpaper

using the example from GraphicsMagick web-sight

```
gm display 300x350+150+200! ~/imagetesting/image1.jpg
```

I get this

```
gm display: Unable to open file (300x350+150+200!) [No such file or directory].
```

then there window pops open with the image in it after it tells me [No such file or directory], and there it is but not up as Wallpaper.

maybe I am wrong and it is a X windows thing, that may have to do with layers or something. I am running openbox, does it not work off an X window or is an X window? 
should I be now investing X Window or is me or is it this thing called GraphicsMagick really not working in that capacity?

Answer (score 0):

You were missing "-geometry"

```
gm display -geometry 300x350+150+200! file.jpg
```